# Add div to each row in loop

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to query post images to be displayed on the homepage of a WordPress website.

I want the final result to look like this
 - [image]

I can get the spans to show up correctly, but I have no clue how to add Bootstrap's 'row' class to each row.

Here is what I have so far -

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => 10,);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<section id="our-work">';

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

     $counter += 1;

     if($counter == 4 || $counter == 5 || $counter == 9 || $counter == 10) : 

     echo '<div class="span6">';
     the_post_thumbnail();;
     echo '</div>';

     else:

     echo '<div class="span4">';
     the_post_thumbnail();
     echo '</div>';

     endif;


 endwhile; endif;

echo '</section>';
```

Comment: Not for nothing, but I really wish php didn't maintain that VB-esque syntax. readability--;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is definitely a more elegant way to do this... but this should work.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => 10,);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<section id="our-work">';

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    $counter += 1;

    if ($counter == 1 || $counter == 4 || $counter == 6 || $counter == 9) {
      echo '<div class="row">';
    }

    if($counter == 4 || $counter == 5 || $counter == 9 || $counter == 10) : 

    echo '<div class="span6">';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</div>';

    else:

    echo '<div class="span4">';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</div>';

    endif;

    if ($counter == 3 || $counter == 5 || $counter == 8 || $counter == 10) {
      echo '</div>';
    }

 endwhile; endif;

echo '</section>';
```

Answer (score 2):

No doubt it could be written differently - or better for that matter, but this should do the trick :)

```
if($counter % 3 == 0) {
    $current_class = "span6";
} else {
    $current_class = "span4";
}

// your stuff here
echo '<div class="'.$current_class.'">';
```